# systemd service won't start because of unconfined_u context?

Tags: centos, systemd, selinux

So I'm trying to start a service (let's call it the "kite agent" and it's a binary executable that runs as part of a tracing service) with systemd via ansible deployment on CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004.

This is the kite_agent.service file that systemd uses:

```
[Unit]
Description=kite_agent
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/kite_agent/kite-agent --config-file=/kite_agent/kite-agent.yml
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=kite-agent
User=kite
Group=kite

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The "/kite_agent" directory in the above .service file has the following permissions:

```
dr-x------.   2 kite kite unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0  117 Jul 21 10:42 kite_agent
```

The files inside "/kite_agent" have the following permissions (as described by `ls -laZ`):

```
dr-x------.  2 kite kite unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0      117 Jul 21 10:42 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root   root   system_u:object_r:root_t:s0             256 Jul 21 10:41 ..
-r--------.  1 kite kite system_u:object_r:default_t:s0         1769 Jul 21 10:42 agent.cert
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root   system_u:object_r:default_t:s0         1582 Jul 21 10:42 agent.csr
-r--------.  1 kite kite system_u:object_r:default_t:s0         3243 Jul 21 10:42 agent.key
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 kite kite system_u:object_r:default_t:s0         1696 Jul 21 10:42 ca.cert
-r-xr-xr-x.  1 kite kite system_u:object_r:default_t:s0     25956781 Jul 21 10:41 kite-agent
-r-xr-xr-x.  1 kite kite system_u:object_r:default_t:s0          256 Jul 21 10:42 kite-agent.yml
```

Am I right in thinking that the "/kite_agent" directory should have permissions with a "system_u" context such as:

```
kite kite system_u:object_r:default_t:s0
```

I'm seeing messages such as the below via journalctl:

```
kite_agent.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /kite_agent/kite-agent: Permission denied

kite_agent.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
```

EDIT:

Including some more basic diagnostic information below:

Running `systemctl status auditd` yields:

```
● auditd.service
   Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit auditd.service is masked.)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Running `cat /etc/audit/auditd.conf` yields:

```
#
# Controls the configuration of the audit daemon
#

local_events = yes
write_logs = yes
log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
log_group = root
log_format = ENRICHED
flush = INCREMENTAL_ASYNC
freq = 50
max_log_file = 8
num_logs = 5
priority_boost = 4
name_format = NONE
##name = mydomain
max_log_file_action = ROTATE
space_left = 75
space_left_action = SYSLOG
verify_email = yes
action_mail_acct = root
admin_space_left = 50
admin_space_left_action = SUSPEND
disk_full_action = SUSPEND
disk_error_action = SUSPEND
use_libwrap = yes
##tcp_listen_port = 60
tcp_listen_queue = 5
tcp_max_per_addr = 1
##tcp_client_ports = 1024-65535
tcp_client_max_idle = 0
transport = TCP
krb5_principal = auditd
##krb5_key_file = /etc/audit/audit.key
distribute_network = no
q_depth = 400
overflow_action = SYSLOG
max_restarts = 10
plugin_dir = /etc/audit/plugins.d
```

Running `audit2allow -a` yields:

```
#============= ifconfig_t ==============
allow ifconfig_t vmware_log_t:file write;
```

Running `ausearch -m avc | grep kite` yields nothing unfortunately.

Running `systemctl status auditd` yields:

```
● auditd.service - Security Auditing Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/auditd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-09-15 16:03:04 CDT; 6min ago
     Docs: man:auditd(8)
           https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/
  Process: 157748 ExecStartPost=/sbin/augenrules --load (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 157747 ExecStart=/sbin/auditd -n (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 157747 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 15 16:03:04 my_app augenrules[157748]: enabled 1
Sep 15 16:03:04 my_app augenrules[157748]: failure 1
Sep 15 16:03:04 my_app augenrules[157748]: pid 2094
Sep 15 16:03:04 my_app augenrules[157748]: rate_limit 0
Sep 15 16:03:04 my_app augenrules[157748]: backlog_limit 8192
Sep 15 16:03:04 my_app augenrules[157748]: lost 0
Sep 15 16:03:04 my_app augenrules[157748]: backlog 0
Sep 15 16:03:04 my_app augenrules[157748]: backlog_wait_time 60000
Sep 15 16:03:04 my_app systemd[1]: auditd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 15 16:03:04 my_app systemd[1]: Failed to start Security Auditing Service.
```

Comment: Did you restart the auditd daemon?  This platform isn't really suited to walking you through step-by-step.  It does presume upon doing some of your own research.   What else have you tried that isn't written here?  I don't really see how the `audit2allow` results you show are relevant.  If the audit daemon isn't running at the time the kite agent fails to start, you can't be sure anything will return appropriate avc information.

Comment: Also you aren't answering ALL questions I've asked or indicating what you have tried ALL the suggestions.  It gets pretty frustrating trying to help when responses do not indicate what all has been tried, etc.  Please re-read the answer and address all details.  We cannot help without adequate information and feedback.

Comment: Did you try the chcon / semanage suggestions?  Figuring out what it broken on the system regarding auditd could indicate deeper issues bleeding over into multiple areas.  How established is this system?  Can you try all this on a relatively clean system so you can gain confidence in what to do on this system.  Somewhere I read that if auditd isn't running, messages might go to rsyslog.  Working without error reporting figured out kind of leaves one blind.

Answer (score 3):

It is not at all surprising that SELinux stops a service from running from a directory that does not have contexts that indicate it is an authorized system service.

More than likely, the directory where the executable resides needs to have a context more like:

```
system_u:object_r:bin_t
```

Perhaps this might suffice:

```
# chcon -u system_u -r object_r -t bin_t /kite_agent
```

but posting the related messages from `/var/log/audit/audit.log` is recommended.  Perhaps getting them is as simple as:

```
# grep kite /var/log.audit/audit.log
```

-or-

```
# ausearch -m avc | grep kite
```

If these commands are not effective, investigate the configuration and/or status of the audit service.

```
# systemctl status auditd
# cat /etc/audit/auditd.conf
```

If the `auditd` service is dead, fix that issue.  It may be as simple as:

```
# systemctl start auditd
```

With a relevant AVC message from the audit log, it is possible to use `audit2allow` to get suggestions on how to fix the issue from SELinux own perspective, but sometimes there are various suggestions.

https://opensource.com/article/18/7/sysadmin-guide-selinux offers a variety of concise tips on working with SELinux.  From that page, the following may be of help in fixing a labeling problem (though some of the details were changed to anticipate the actual answer to this question).  A caveat is that this snippet leaves off other parts of the context, so `man semanage-fcontext` is probably helpful too.  :

```
Labeling problem: If your files in /kite_agent are not labeled correctly, access might be denied. Here are some ways to fix this:
    If you know the label:
    # semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t '/kite_agent(/.*)?'
    If you know the file with the equivalent labeling:
    # semanage fcontext -a -e /kite_agent /path/to/dir
    Restore the context (for both cases):
    # restorecon -vR /kite_agent
```

Considering that `/usr/sbin` contains some other services this could be appropriate, but do be sure that it is:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -e /kite_agent /usr/sbin
# restorecon -vR /kite_agent
```

The page also offers troubleshooting tips.  Naturally, there are more detailed documents out there, particularly on RedHat or CentOS sites.

If the AVC details are added to the question, perhaps some more specific help could be forthcoming.

Comment: So in my case I think the log is in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, but "grep-ing" for kite doesn't yield any results...very odd...

Comment: I presume the results of `getenforce` is "Enforcing".  I'm actually looking on my own CentOS 8 sytem at the moment.  I've added some detail in the last few minutes.  It might be worth looking back over the answer.

Comment: You can also just run "audit2allow -a" to see a list of various things to related to currently known SELinux blocks, but do not indiscriminately do everything it suggests since legitimately blocked issues may have contributed to the results.  It is much preferred to find the specific AVC and analyze it specifically so as not to inadvertently authorize some malware from doing something evil.

Comment: Yes the result of getenforce is "Enforcing". Any idea why nothing about kite_service is being written to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`? I'm trying audit2allow -a now.

Comment: Interesting - if I do "setenforce 0", the service will run...

Comment: Yes, of course, SELinux is effectively disabled by `setenforce 0`.  Did you try running `ausearch -m avc`?  What is the output of `systemctl status auditd`?  What is in `/etc/audit/auditd.conf`?

Comment: Please add the additional information to the question rather than to put it in comments.

Comment: Ok, updated the question, thanks